# xpath : compare tokenized list with another tokenized list

Tags: xpath

In xslt I have a variable which has a single string with space as delimiter.
var_1 = 'cat dog cow'

The following xml is present for which the 'name' attribute has value with space as delimiter.

```
<top_element>

<element_10>    
<element_11>    
<element_000 name="cow cat">
string_1 
</element_000>
</element_11>
</element_10>    

<element_20 name="bat">
<element_21>        
<element_000 name="cow cat">
string_2
</element_000>
</element_21>
</element_20>   

<element_30 name="bat dog">
<element_31>        
<element_000 name="cow cat">
string_3
</element_000>
</element_31>
</element_30>

<element_40 >
<element_41>        
<element_000 name="cow bat">
string_4
</element_000>
</element_41>
</element_40>

</top_element>
```

Question:

Handle the element_000 in the xml only if, for ancestor or self of element:

1. name attribute is not defined or
2. value of 'name' attribute contains at least one value of 'var_1.

While parsing the xml using xslt, the output html should contain only the following strings:
string_1
string_3
string_4

The string_2 should not be displayed, as its ancestor  has name value which does not match with any of the values in the var_1 list.

My try:
Note: I am using xslt version 2.0

```
<xsl:template match="element_000">
<choose>
<xsl:when test"(ancestor-or-self::*[(tokenize(@name,'\s+')) != (tokenize($var_1,'\s+'))])">
```

<--Handle the element-->

```
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

This approach did not work for me. Please let me know if this is possible by some other way.

Thanks
SRB.

Comment: In your prerequisites for showing the output you say that the match can be in _ancestor or self of element_. However, `string_2` is not to be shown since _although_ there are two matches (`cat` and `cow`) for `self`. Isn't that a contradiction?

Comment: If the parent/ancestor element has name attribute set and its value does not match with any of the var_1 values then string_2 should not get displayed.

Comment: So the condition would be `((match in name in self) or (name in self empty)) and ((name in ancestor empty) or (match in name in ancestor))`? Basically, you have to replace the top level `or` by `and`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes exactly I want the same thing. But there is no provision in xpath for ancestor-and-self. Am I right? Do you have any technique to do the same. Please share.

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="var_1" select="'cat dog cow'"/>
<xsl:variable name="names" select="tokenize($var_1, ' ')"/>

<xsl:template match="text()"/>

<xsl:template match="element_000[every $el in ancestor-or-self::* 
                                 satisfies (not(exists($el/@name)) or $names = tokenize($el/@name, ' '))]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

then the output contains only the elements

```
<element_000 name="cow cat">
string_1
</element_000><element_000 name="cow cat">
string_3
</element_000><element_000 name="cow bat">
string_4
</element_000>
```

Comment: Thank You. Am I suppose to add any name space to get this work? During run time it is failing. Theoretically, with this change I think that the string 5 also get selected which is not expected (In the below mentioned example). Please let me know if this is so.   <element_50>
<element_51>        
<element_000 name="crow snake">
string_5
</element_000>
</element_51>
</element_50>

Comment: @srb, which XSLT 2.0 processor do you use, which failure error message or behaviour exactly do you get?

Comment: @srb, as for that `<element_000 name="crow snake"> string_5 </element_000>`, it will not be output as it has a `name` attribute with values where none is equal to any in `$names`.

Comment: It is not showing any error message in the console. It simple quits without generating the output file.

Comment: I am using your code as follows: 
<xsl:template match="element_000">
<choose>
<xsl:when test"(every $el in ancestor-or-self::*satisfies (not(exists($el/@name)) or $names = tokenize($el/@name, ' ')))">
<xsl:value-of select="'1'"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="'0'"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

Comment: I am using saxon 9.0.